# Aggregating a spark dataframe and counting based whether a value exists in a array type column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a array type column:

```
scala> mydf.printSchema
root
 |-- arraycol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
```

I now need to aggregate this dataframe by "**id**" and count based on whether a particular value exists in the array. I was trying to do this:

```
val aggdata = mydf.groupBy("id").
  agg(
    count(when($"arraycol" contains "someval", $"arraycol")).as("aggval"))
```

That doesn't seem to work. Any inputs how I can do this?

Comment: pls provide sample input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `array_contains` method to test the condition:

```scala
val df = Seq((1, Seq("a", "b")), (1, Seq("b")), (2, Seq("b"))).toDF("id", "arrayCol")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, arrayCol: array<string>]

df.show
+---+--------+
| id|arrayCol|
+---+--------+
|  1|  [a, b]|
|  1|     [b]|
|  2|     [b]|
+---+--------+


df.groupBy("id").agg(
  count(when(array_contains($"arrayCol", "a"), $"arrayCol")).as("hasA")
).show
+---+----+
| id|hasA|
+---+----+
|  1|   1|
|  2|   0|
+---+----+
```

Or use `sum`:

```scala
df.groupBy("id").agg(
  sum(when(array_contains($"arrayCol", "a"), 1).otherwise(0)).as("hasA")
).show
+---+----+
| id|hasA|
+---+----+
|  1|   1|
|  2|   0|
+---+----+
```

Comment: thx for your reply! Unfortunately we are using 2.3 at my organizations. Any options on that version of spark?

Comment: array_contains is available since Spark 1.5 Version. So you should be good to use this.

Comment: @RamdevSharma Ahh. Right. Confused with all the new array functions added in `2.4`